# I'm lost trying to install matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation

I'm trying to install matplotlib but I get the "build wheel error". I've tried everything I could find online but nothing did resolve the issue.

```
  Building wheel for matplotlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for matplotlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [683 lines of output]
      /private/var/folders/fd/c31_42nd73q0nnzbm04bflr40000gn/T/pip-build-env-4oi1k753/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:955: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The namespace_packages parameter is deprecated.
```

Then I found probably my problem but I have no clue how to solve this. If anyone can help me, that would be much appreciated.

I've upgraded `pip`, `setuptools` and I have the newest version of Python and `wheel` installed.

Comment: have you tried installing it using Anaconda? Install python from Anaconda then try `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib`. it downloads prebuilt packages

Comment: What command produces this error?

Comment: A deprecation warning is not an error, it's just -- as the name says -- a warning. If you're leaving out other logs to show us only that warning, you're probably hiding the real problem.

Comment: (While @AliEnt isn't offering _bad_ advice, personally, I would use [Nix](https://nixos.org/) instead of Conda; it has stronger reproducibility guarantees -- running builds inside a sandbox with no access to files other than their declared dependencies -- so it's much harder for something to work on person-A's machine but not person-B's in the Nix world; and it offers those same guarantees for software written in more languages than just Python).

Comment: ...indeed, running Nix on MacOS myself, `nix-shell -p '((import <nixpkgs> {}).python3.withPackages (p: [p.matplotlib]))'` plonks me down in a shell where the default Python has matplotlib installed without any issue.

Comment: Thanks to all for your help. I'm gonna try Anaconda first and if it doesn't work then I'll try Nix.

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.